# Merge consecutive time record in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, common-table-expression, row-number

Say I have data like this, timeslots is basically time with 30 mins apart.
Note there is a gap in 2021-12-24 between 15:30 and 16:30.

| calender_date | timeslot | timeslot_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-24 | 14:00:00 | 14:30:00 |
| 2021-12-24 | 14:30:00 | 15:00:00 |
| 2021-12-24 | 15:00:00 | 15:30:00 |
| 2021-12-24 | 16:30:00 | 17:00:00 |
| 2021-12-24 | 17:00:00 | 17:30:00 |
| 2021-12-24 | 17:30:00 | 18:00:00 |
| 2021-12-30 | 09:00:00 | 09:30:00 |
| 2021-12-30 | 09:30:00 | 10:00:00 |

I want to merge rows where timeslot_end = next row's timeslot and in the same day, so data would look like this.

| calender_date | timeslot | timeslot_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-24 | 14:00:00 | 15:30:00 |
| 2021-12-24 | 16:30:00 | 18:00:00 |
| 2021-12-30 | 9:00:00 | 10:00:00 |

I have try row numbering with self join,

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT       
                calender_date 
                ,timeslot
                ,timeslot_end
                ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY [timeslot])rn
    
    FROM @tmp_leave tl
)

SELECT  
        MIN(a.timeslot) OVER(PARTITION BY a.calender_date, DATEDIFF(minute,a.timeslot_end, 
            ISNULL(b.timeslot, a.timeslot_end))) AS 'StartTime',
        MAX(a.timeslot_end ) OVER(PARTITION BY a.calender_date, 
            DATEDIFF(minute,a.timeslot_end, ISNULL(b.timeslot, a.timeslot_end))) AS 'EndTime'
        
FROM cte a 
LEFT JOIN cte b
       ON a.rn + 1 = b.rn AND a.timeslot_end = b.timeslot
ORDER BY calender_date
```

But the result isn't quite right, it ignored the gap in 2021-12-24 and return below.

| calender_date | timeslot | timeslot_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-24 | 14:00:00 | 18:00:00 |
| 2021-12-30 | 9:00:00 | 10:00:00 |

I have been searching and trying to solve it for a while now, please help, any help is very very appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

This is a gaps and islands problem.  We can approach this by creating pseudo groups for each island of continuous dates/times.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, LAG(timeslot_end) OVER
                  (ORDER BY calendar_date, timeslot) timeslot_end_lag
    FROM yourTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(CASE WHEN timeslot_end_lag <> timeslot THEN 1 END)
                  OVER (ORDER BY calendar_date, timeslot) AS grp
    FROM cte
)

SELECT calendar_date,
       MIN(timeslot) AS timeslot,
       MAX(timeslot_end) AS timeslot_end
FROM cte2
GROUP BY calendar_date, grp
ORDER BY calendar_date;
```

### Demo

Comment: Hi Tim, Thank you for the help! My first though on the code you provided is that I am in sql server 2008 so no LAG() function for me, I haven't look into the rest of the code but I bet it will help, also the gap and islands problem is something I haven't heard before, I definately gonna looking into that.

Comment: @Cheese May we ask why you are still using SSMS 2008?  It probably isn't supported anymore, and there could be security holes which would make your application vulnerable to attacks.  Consider upgrading as soon as you can.

Comment: It is a old system and me myself don't have a say on what version we are using, unfortunately. Though I belive we will switch to newer version in a year.